# How to add the index of the array as a field to an array of structs in pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe containing an array of structs. I would like to add the index of the array as a field within the struct. Is this possible?

So structure would go from:

```
|-- my_array_column: array
 |    |-- element: struct
 |    |    |-- field1: string
 |    |    |-- field2: string
```

to:

```
|-- my_array_column: array
 |    |-- element: struct
 |    |    |-- field1: string
 |    |    |-- field2: string
 |    |    |-- index of element: integer
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Spark 3.1+, you can use `transform` function and `withField` to update each struct element of the array column like his:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "my_array_column",
    F.transform("my_array_column", lambda x, i: x.withField("index", i))
)
```

For older version, you'll have to recreate the whole struct element in order to add a field:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    "my_array_column",
    F.expr("transform(my_array_column, (x, i) -> struct(x.field1 as field1, x.field2 as field2, i as index))")
)
```

Comment: noice! much better and straightforward than using `aggregate()`

Comment: This is perfect, i didn't realise transform could access the index of the element in the second argument of the lambda like that.
Documentation for reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html